# Stumbling with join and selecting from separate table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have three separate tables - `pages`, `tags`, and `pages_tagged` - that contain **page content**, **tag names** and **ids**, and **page ids** with **tag ids** respectively.

I'm trying to set up a MySQL query that takes the search term and checks for an existing tag, finds the matching tag ID, and returns all pages with said tag - I've got this working well. However, when I try to extend it further to also query matching string within the title column of the pages table, things go a bit belly-up.

My SQL is as follows:

```
SELECT tags.id, pages_tagged.page_id, pages.id, pages.randomId, pages.title, 
       DATE_FORMAT( pages.dateAdded,  '%M %e, %Y' ) AS dateAdded, 
       pages.viewcount, pages.sessionId 
FROM tags JOIN pages_tagged ON tags.id = pages_tagged.tag_id 
JOIN pages ON pages_tagged.page_id = pages.randomId 
WHERE (tags.tag = 'ovechkin' OR pages.title LIKE '%ovechkin%')
ORDER BY dateAdded DESC
```

I know that the order of operations here is very wrong, but I can't wrap my head around the correct way to modify this query to make it work correctly.

Would anyone be able to point out my glaring errors?

**Edit:**

To clarify "belly-up," when the query is run, it's "successful." However, no rows are ever returned.

Modifying the WHERE clause as follows to isolate the pages.title LIKE '%ovechkin%' never results in returned rows, no matter what the search term is.

```
WHERE (pages.title LIKE '%ovechkin%')
```

**Edit 2:**

Sample data below.

```
pages
╔════╦════════════════════════╦═════════════════════╦══════════╦═══════════╗
║ id ║         title          ║      dateAdded      ║ randomId ║ viewcount ║
╠════╬════════════════════════╬═════════════════════╬══════════╬═══════════╣
║ 57 ║ Ovechkin looping about ║ 2013-04-07 19:26:06 ║ xp3rvju  ║         5 ║
╚════╩════════════════════════╩═════════════════════╩══════════╩═══════════╝

tags
╔════════╦══════════╗
║ id     ║ tag      ║
╠════════╬══════════╣
║     25 ║ ovechkin ║
╚════════╩══════════╝

pages_tagged
╔══════════════════╗
║ tag_id | page_id ║
╠══════════════════╣
║ 25 | xp3rvju     ║
║ 25 | mpbjbk6     ║
╚══════════════════╝
```

**Edit 3:**

As suggested, a `RIGHT JOIN` gets the `pages.title` working. The modified query is:

```
SELECT tags.id, pages_tagged.page_id, pages.id, pages.randomId, pages.title, 
   DATE_FORMAT( pages.dateAdded,  '%M %e, %Y' ) AS dateAdded, 
   pages.viewcount, pages.sessionId 
FROM tags RIGHT JOIN pages_tagged ON tags.id = pages_tagged.tag_id 
RIGHT JOIN pages ON pages_tagged.page_id = pages.randomId 
WHERE (tags.tag = 'ovechkin' OR pages.title LIKE '%ovechkin%')
ORDER BY dateAdded DESC
```

A remaining concern is that if a page has the same search term in both its title and an associated tag, it'll return twice. I've tried modifying it to include `DISTINCT` on the select, as follows, but this doesn't have an impact on the returned rows.

```
SELECT DISTINCT tags.id, pages_tagged.page_id, pages.id, pages.randomId, pages.title, 
   DATE_FORMAT( pages.dateAdded,  '%M %e, %Y' ) AS dateAdded,
```

**Edit 4:**

May as well include the final solution to prevent duplicates - `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT tags.id, pages_tagged.page_id, pages.id, pages.randomId, pages.title, 
   DATE_FORMAT( pages.dateAdded,  '%M %e, %Y' ) AS dateAdded, 
   pages.viewcount, pages.sessionId 
FROM pages 
LEFT JOIN pages_tagged ON pages.randomId = pages_tagged.page_id 
LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.id = pages_tagged.tag_id 
WHERE (tags.tag = 'ovechkin' OR pages.title LIKE '%ovechkin%')
GROUP BY pages.randomId
ORDER BY dateAdded DESC
```

Comment: Can you explain "things go a bit belly-up" - what results do you see as opposed to what you would expect to see? (FWIW, the existing query looks OK.)

Comment: Of course!

The query runs "successfully," but no results are actually returned. Removing tags.tag = 'thang' has no impact, but no matter what the search term under pages.title LIKE '%term%' is, no rows are returned.

Comment: Can you post some relevant sample data?

Comment: I've just noticed - shouldn't the the join to pages be on `pages.id`, not `pages.randomId`?

Comment: @MarkBannister: I was wondering the same thing, also this query will not return any pages that aren't tagged.

Comment: Following the added sample data, apparently not.

Comment: Had some formatting trouble with the sample data, will try to get that up again. For pages.id, it's actually going to pages.randomId due to the way I'm identifying content - probably not ideal, but working well otherwise.

Comment: I've updated the original post to include properly-formatted sample data!

Comment: When I run your query with your sample data, I get results - see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a34524/1

Comment: Well, that's bizarre - even if I isolate the pages.title as the only condition, it works in the fiddle. However, the same query doesn't work in phpmyadmin - is there anything I might be missing here?

Comment: It might be partially related to the collation - the SQLFiddle instance of MySQL is obviously using a case-insensitive collation, otherwise the pages.title condition on its own would not return any data (since the pages.title values is `Ovechkin looping about` with a capital `O`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is important to understand how joins work in general, here is a simple explanation: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Since you are are looking for a tag `OR` a match in the title, I'm guessing you want to be using a `RIGHT JOIN` for the relation, because this query will not return any pages that aren't tagged.

Currently, if you have a page with the title `ovechkin` but no tags, you won't find it using this query.

This is what I tried: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c25c5/2

Generally, the way the query is built means that you are getting all tags, then joining any tagged pages. The behaviour without the `WHERE` clause is as follows:

Doing a normal `JOIN` will just return tagged pages, if there are no tags in the database you wont get a single row.

Using a `LEFT JOIN` means you get a result for each tag, even if no pages are tagged.

Using `RIGHT JOIN` means you will get all result row for all the pages, even if there are no tags, or no pages are tagged.

For all of these, any fields where there is no data will be filled with null.

I would recommend changing the query to this (certain fields removed for readability):

```
SELECT tags.id, pages_tagged.page_id, pages.id, pages.randomId
FROM pages 
LEFT JOIN pages_tagged ON pages.randomId = pages_tagged.page_id 
LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.id = pages_tagged.tag_id

WHERE (tags.tag = 'ovechkin' OR pages.title LIKE '%ovechkin%')
```

You will get the same page more than once if it has more than one tag.

Comment: This is excellent to know - I didn't realize that that would happen as a result. I'll see if it makes any difference..

Comment: correction, the way the query is now it should be a right join, i edited the answer

Comment: A right join as you illustrated makes this work! Seems like a simple fix. That being said, I appear to be running into a second issue where if a page has the search term in both the tags and the title, it'll be returned twice - is there a way to prevent duplicates?

Comment: use `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY pages.randomId` if you want unique results

Comment: `GROUP BY pages.randomId` works like a charm. Thanks for your help!

Comment: glad it helped! try to understand the concepts behind joins as well! It will really help you in the future. I extended my answer a little to help with that.

Comment: I'll be sure to dive into the join concepts further! One quick thought - your suggested example uses `LEFT JOIN` rather than `RIGHT JOIN`, which I think reverted on one of your earlier edits.

Comment: the result will be the same in this case, because I am using `FROM pages` instead of `FROM tags`. In my opinion the more logical query, as you are searching pages - not tags. With your original query you have to use a `RIGHT JOIN` though.

Comment: Of course - somehow I missed that switch. I agree that it's more logical - implemented it myself!

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
 select * from
   (SELECT tags.id as tid, pages_tagged.page_id, pages.id, pages.randomId, pages.title, 
           DATE_FORMAT( pages.dateAdded,  '%M %e, %Y' ) AS dateAdded, 
           pages.viewcount, pages.sessionId 
    FROM tags JOIN pages_tagged ON tags.id = pages_tagged.tag_id 
    JOIN pages ON pages_tagged.page_id = pages.randomId 
    WHERE tags.tag = 'thang' 
    union
    ( SELECT tags.id as tid, pages_tagged.page_id, pages.id, pages.randomId, pages.title, 
           DATE_FORMAT( pages.dateAdded,  '%M %e, %Y' ) AS dateAdded, 
           pages.viewcount, pages.sessionId 
     FROM pages JOIN pages_tagged on pages_tagged.page_id = pages.randomId
     JOIN tags ON tags.id = pages_tagged.tag_id   
     WHERE           pages.title LIKE '%thang%'
    )
  ) as a
    ORDER BY a.dateAdded DESC
```

That way it will choose first "correct" tags after that "correct" pages.

Comment: why didn't you stick with the left join? I think that would have sufficed

Comment: i have changed answer. Tr this variant.

Comment: I seem to be hitting `Duplicate column name 'id'` with this - but I'm not entirely sure where it's coming from.